# Made image is not shown in html

Tags: python, html, django

Made image is not shown in html.
I wrote in views.py

```
@login_required
def view_plot(request):
    left = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    height = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500])
    plt.bar(left, height)
    filename = "output.png"
    save_fig=plt.savefig(filename)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/png")
    save_fig.save(response, "PNG")
    return save_fig
```

in html

```
  <body>
    <img src='/accounts/view_plot' width=300 height=300>
  </body>
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^view_plot$', views.view_plot,name='view_plot'),
]
```

But now ,web page is like
[image]

cracked image is shown.

I do not know why this error happens.
In Django app,output.png is saved.
I doubt image is not made in view_plot.But i cannot know whether or not.
What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Comment: Not a direct solution but you might like to try showing the image as a base64 array so you don't have to clog a server with loads of image files... There an example of how to do this in [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31719138/1324033)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your STATIC_URL: '/static/' Set in settings.py. Then your static files like images should be in

```
-MyProject
--Static
---css
---js
---img
----all images
```

Then in your html template.

```
{% load static %}
<body>
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
</body>
```

Check the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) for static files info.